# How to know what day the user touched in a date picker in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

Good afternoon community,

I would like to know if there is any way to recognize which day was pressed in a datePicker in swiftui since I want to know what day the user pressed and be able to save it in a variable?

```
DatePicker("My calendar", selection: $startDate,in:Date()..., displayedComponents: .date)
        
        .accentColor(.Teal)
        .background(
                       RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                        .stroke(Color.Teal, lineWidth: 3)
                    )
        .labelsHidden()
        .environment(\.colorScheme, .dark)
        .datePickerStyle(GraphicalDatePickerStyle())
        .padding()
        }
```

[image]

As in the photo, how do I know that the user made a tap on day 12 or 13, is there a delegate to know that in swiftui?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`onChange(of:perform:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onchange(of:perform:)) modifier to detect changes in the selected date:

```
.onChange(of: startDate) { newDate in
    print("selected date: \(newDate)")

    let day = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: newDate).day!
    print("day: \(day)")
}
```

Example prints:

> selected date: 2021-08-20 21:59:00 +0000
> day: 20

Answer (score 1):

You defined *$startDate* for *selection*. You need a state variable named *startDate* to store the selected Date.

For full explanation follow this link: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-a-date-picker-and-read-values-from-it

*Edit:*
And as @George mentioned if you want to detect the change of the state variable use the [onChange(of:perform:)](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-run-some-code-when-state-changes-using-onchange) modifier.